# Cannot remove eventlistener from noname remote callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, event-listener

I put a listener to process in a noname function (because I have to transmit some data further - 'evt' and 'ref' for example). How to close a listener in another remote file, were I process this data.

**index.js**:

```js
import onClick from "./onClick.js";
const ref = document.querySelector('h1');
ref.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {onClick(evt, ref)}
```

**onClick.js**:

```js
export default function onClick(evt, ref) {
    console.log(evt);
    ref.removeEventListener('click', onClick)
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by `onClick()` is not correct? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for a bad explanation. I put a listener on a noname function (because I have to transmit some data further - 'ref' for example). How to close a listener in another remote file, were I process this data.

Comment: So just give it a name?

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the anonymous function to a variable to have a function name, and pass it to onClick function. It seems to be anti-pattern (passing callee function to caller), but I guess this is what you're looking for:

**index.js**

```
import onClick from "./onClick.js";


const ref = document.querySelector('h1');

function clickCb(evt) { 
  onClick(evt, ref, clickCb) 
}

ref.addEventListener('click', clickCb}
```

**onClick.js**

```
export default function onClick(evt, ref, clickCb) {
    console.log(evt);
    ref.removeEventListener('click', clickCb)
};
```

Comment: Yes, but we need to export ClickCb from index.js and import to onClick.js - it works, but code become so confused.

Comment: Why do you need to export and import clickCb? Is passed as argument, like any other function. There shouldn't be any need to export or import it

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll try this !